# Enabling CORS in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have read through a lot of the stuff over enabling CORS in my web api.

I installed the NuGet Package and added this line to my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

I can't actually compile my code though because it says it does not have a definition for `EnableCORS`.

So... what is wrong?  (Yes, I did install the CORS package using this:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Comment: See [EnableCorsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: @abatishchev I already have `using System.Web.Http;` added. So shouldn't `System.Web.Http.Cors` be added already?

Comment: No, each namespace should be added separately. Also pay attention to the casing: `EnableCORS` and `EnableCors`.

Comment: Hmmm, It says that Cors does not exist in System.Web.Http;

Comment: Check you actually reference the dll from the project. And you don't have any compiler warnings preventing its referencing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I played with VS2013 and restarted it a few times.... rechecked that I had the NuGet package installed (I had to reinstall it....) Now it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to do like this

1. remove all custom headers from your web.config
2. Add this reference in your web api project:

   > System.Web.Http.Cors
3. add the following line code inside the **Register** **method** of the **WebApiConfig** class.

   > config.EnableCors();
4. Add the following attribute in your controller(s)

   > [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*",
   >   SupportsCredentials = true)]